# How to do a like filter using an external table in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a Spark SQL query to take a set of values from a reference table and use them to filter rows from a main table.

Current SQL looks like:

```
select time, code, user, message from TABLE where
  (code = 'x' and (user like '%USER1%' or user like '%USER2%') and not (message like '%PREFIX1:HOST1%' or message like '%PREFIX1:HOST2%')) or
  (code = 'y' and (user like '%USER1%' or user like '%USER2%') and not (message like '%PREFIX2:HOST1%' or message like '%PREFIX2:HOST2%'))
```

I should be able to change the above to something like:

```
select time, code, user, message from TABLE where
  (code = 'x' and user rlike '(USER1|USER2)' and not message rlike 'PREFIX1:(HOST1|HOST2)') or
  (code = 'y' and user rlike '(USER1|USER2)' and not message rlike 'PREFIX2:(HOST1|HOST2)')
```

But ideally I was hoping to be able to use an external table to prevent having to load the users / hosts into the sql multiple times and possibly hitting maximum length limits around the sql (the users set is smallish, the set of hosts consists of several hundred hosts and can be updated), something like:

```
Table USERS { username: String }
Table HOSTS { hostname: String }

select time, code, user, message from TABLE where
  (code = 'x' and user rlike '<ANY username FROM USERS>' and not message rlike 'PREFIX1:<ANY hostname FROM HOSTS>') or
  (code = 'y' and user rlike '<ANY username FROM USERS>' and not message rlike 'PREFIX2:<ANY hostname FROM HOSTS>')
```

I think an exact match above would be simple to implement but because it is a like match it seems a bit harder.

I suspect I should be able to get something working using data frames however I would likely have similar limitations just with different syntax.  Eg. filter would look something like:

```
df.filter($"message".rlike("PREFIX1:(HOST1|HOST2|HOST3)")
```

The other option is to run better parsing logic before I hit this point so I can do an exact match which could work out easier but also makes it more difficult to represent in a DSL that a customer could use.  Ideally I would like to be able to represent matching one of many values in a field.

Comment: You can move entire where condition to filter(). `df.filter("(code = 'x' and user rlike '<ANY username FROM USERS>' and not message rlike 'PREFIX1:<ANY hostname FROM HOSTS>') or (code = 'y' and user rlike '<ANY username FROM USERS>' and not message rlike 'PREFIX2:<ANY hostname FROM HOSTS>')")`

Comment: Let us know if help needed in writing exact condition.

Comment: @mrsrinivas I can do the equivalent work in sql or data frames but what I'm not sure how to do is to use a table to set the <ANY hostname FROM HOSTS>, I can directly write that eg. rlike 'PREFIX2:(host1|host2|host3)' but I want to be able to write something like rlike 'PREFIX2:(select hostname from HOSTS)' which will use the values from the HOSTS table directly rather than me having to translate them across myself.  I wonder if I can do something using user defined functions.

Comment: does hostnames in where condition limited set ?